# Are there any rules for determining accent phrases?

Tags: phrases, pitch-accent

Recently, I've been doing Japanese language processing. As far as I know, Japanese is a tone language and there is only one accent nucleus in an accent phrase in most cases. So, basically, there are two major tasks. One is to combine single words into accent phrases. The other is to determine the accent nucleus of accent phrases based on rules proposed in [日本語単語連鎖のアクセント規則](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Emine/japanese/acoustics/sagisaka.pdf).

But the first task is very difficult to me. I've done some research but never found any clear and comprehensive rules for that. There are some rules used in [Open JTalk](https://github.com/r9y9/open_jtalk/blob/1.11/src/njd_set_accent_phrase/njd_set_accent_phrase_rule_utf_8.h) but they are too general to be accurate enough. [OJAD](https://www.gavo.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/%7Emine/japanese/acoustics/OJAD_Kashiwa_White.pdf) doesn't provide any clear rules, either.

Below is a rule from OpenJTalk and an example where it's applied.

```
「動詞」の後に「形容詞」or「名詞」がきたら別のアクセント句に
```

Suppose the input text is 優しい人. First, we can tokenize it into words using MeCab.

```
優しい 形容詞,自立,*,*,形容詞・イ段,基本形,優しい,ヤサシイ,ヤサシイ,0/4,*
人   名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,人,ヒト,ヒト,0/2,C3
```

Since 優しい is 形容詞 and 人 is 名詞, using the rule above, they fall into different accent phrases.

```
優しい#人
```

Another rule is shown below.

```
「助詞」or「助動詞」（付属語）は前にくっつける
```

Suppose the input text is 優しい人ですね.

```
優しい 形容詞,自立,*,*,形容詞・イ段,基本形,優しい,ヤサシイ,ヤサシイ,0/4,*
人   名詞,一般,*,*,*,*,人,ヒト,ヒト,0/2,C3
です  助動詞,*,*,*,特殊・デス,基本形,です,デス,デス’,1/2,名詞%F2@1/動詞%F1/形容詞%F2@0
ね   助詞,終助詞,*,*,*,*,ね,ネ,ネ,1/1,動詞%F1/名詞%F1/形容詞%F1
```

Since です and ね are 助動詞 and 助詞, respectively, they are chained to 人. Still, we get two accent phrases.

```
優しい#人ですね
```

Comment: It's a really big topic. You can write a book about it, but might end up saying that there are several patterns but you need to remember which one the word falls under, like English irregular verbs.

Comment: Also, to my knowledge the current progress of study still cannot distinguish it clearly from the discussion of intonation (if any), so it is expected to be quite complicated.

Comment: ＠broccoli forest Thanks for your comment! I wonder what aspects should be considered in this process? OpenJTalk only uses part-of-speech. For example, 「形容詞」の後に「名詞」がきたら別のアクセント句に。But is it possible that we should also take other aspects like mora size into account?

Comment: Actually, the example in your comment reminds me that there isn't even an agreed definition of "accent phrase": does it mean "a segment until the pitch height resets", "until the next re-raising", or "until the next nucleus (downstep)"?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, "accent phrase" in Japanese means "until the next nucleus". And in most cases, an accent phrase only has one nucleus.

Comment: There are cases where semantic elements play a role, which means you would almost never get a reasonable/small enough set of rules to determine the pitch accent for a given Japanese string. In this sense, it is like article usage in Western languages.

Comment: [This](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/transinf/E100.D/4/E100.D_2016AWI0004/_article) seems to suggest there are no simple rules.